# Prepend a string to all inputs when serializing a JQuery form

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, forms, serialization

I have an asp.net app that does ModelMapping from a submitted form.  Today, I serialize the form and everything works great.  I'm planning on nesting the current data structure (that the form maps to) within a class but the problem is that the class's name can vary.

Today I use Jquery's Serialize command on the form but now I need to prepend the new class name (and a '.') to the various inputs in the form.

Is there a simple way to tell Serialize to prepend a variable name?  Alternatively, does anyone know an easily prepend a class on a set of variables that are serialized?

Comment: You need to prepend a string to all input... values?

Comment: Yes.  But now that you say it like that, I imagine I could just run through all the input values in the form and prepend the class to each's name attribute.

Comment: That's what I didn't get. You want to prepend the class to the input value or to something else. I see no point in going through input values if you are modifying something else.

Comment: Actually the problem is that I do the serialization inline and the query string is created from several pieces.  So it'll look like: ${#form).serialze() + '&abc=xyz&def=uvw".  I need a single function that serializes the form and prepends the text onto each input name.